# Async NancyFX with HttpClient - GetAsync for fbcdn returns 403 forbidden?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dotnet-httpclient, nancy

**NOTE: I've changed this question quite a bit in an attempt to make it point more to the problem. The comments below no longer reflect this question.**

I'm trying to get this image from fbcdn:

https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=6c801f82cd5a32fd6e5a4258ce00a314&oe=589AAD2F

Browser gets it just fine. Here's my code:

```
public class ReverseProxyController : NancyModule
{
    public ReverseProxyController()
    {
        Get["/", true] = async (parameters, ct) =>
        {
            var result = await GetResult(parameters, ct);
            return result;
        };
    }

    private async Task<Response> GetResult(dynamic parameters, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string url = Request.Query["url"].Value.ToString();
        if (url == null) return null;

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6");
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url, ct);

        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();


        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {
            case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                return Response.FromStream(stream, response.Content.Headers.ContentType != null
                    ? response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString()
                    : "application/octet-stream");

            default:
                return Response.AsText("\nError " + response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

I get a 403 Forbidden response every time. I thought adding the headers would make it work but no go.

This code works for other images on other hosts like this one:

https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/ff/f0/c9/fff0c988a4516659d4009f60e0694cb6.jpg

Comment: So `Response.FromStream` and `Response.AsText` from what lib are those ? Or what are they doing ?

Comment: well if thats out of the question, if i test the other code, works fine here with 200 response

Comment: Really? With the fbcdn URL?

Comment: yes sir, with the fbcdn url

Comment: Hmmmm. Ok I'll try that. I didn't think that would make any difference. And it works for other urls just not the fbcdn. I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: Did you try to look at exception or innerexception if available ? Your code just works fine at my end.

Comment: There's .net no exception. It's a 403 response from the fbcdn server.

Comment: Seems that your request has been blocked by server. consider using proxy IP and changing headers...

Comment: Hi Zen...the other poster yesterday said it works if he does the request outside of this Nancy code.

Comment: @richard, Just wrote a unit test to get the url and it works for `http` calls but fails for `https` which i guess has to do with the certificate. It was a simple test with just the url. no other headers. get a 200 OK response

Comment: @Nkosi, it works for some https. For example the URL I have in my question at the media cache site works: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/ff/f0/c9/fff0c988a4516659d4009f60e0694cb6.jpg

Comment: @richard yes my unit tests reflect that as well. So now I'm trying to understand what the problem as my unit tests show that the files can be accessed with a simple getasync on httpclient.

Comment: Does your unit test successfully get the fbcdn image? Also is your unit test using Nancy async?

Comment: unit test gets fbcdn image when using `http` scheme instead of `https`. https throws certificate error. simple async unit test with httpclient calling url.

Comment: Interesting. What's the certificate error? That the fbcdn cert is invalid?

Comment: Unfortunately when I re-ran it for the https to record error, it works now. odd.

Comment: Try it with nancy. See if that's the problem maybe?

Comment: Works fine here, with the example link, just did it with a simple console application, you sure its just not just that some of the links you use is not viewable with out login in ?

Comment: That specific link is not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in URL Retrieval from Nancy request, not getting Data with `HttpClient`.

I Suppose you are sending request to nancy like:

http://localhost/?url=...

hence for Facebook, it would be:

http://localhost/?url=https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=6c801f82cd5a32fd6e5a4258ce00a314&oe=589AAD2F

but for this url `string url = Request.Query["url"].Value.ToString();` is incomplete and missing the last part (&oe=589AAD2F), hence the server responses with Forbidden.

[image]

Here is the simple change to demonstrate the problem:

```
private async Task<Response> GetResult(dynamic parameters, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var req = Request.Url.ToString();
    var queryStart = req.IndexOf("url=");
    if (queryStart == -1)
        return Nancy.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

    var url = req.Substring(queryStart + 4);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        return Nancy.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6");
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url, ct);

    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();


    switch (response.StatusCode)
    {
        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK:
            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            return Response.FromStream(stream, response.Content.Headers.ContentType != null
                ? response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString()
                : "application/octet-stream");

        default:
            return Response.AsText("\nError " + response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

**Solution**

We can actually Encode the URL prior sending it, and Nancy will Automatically decode the URL for us, hence no need to change anything server side.

Here is a link example generated using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` applied on

https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=6c801f82cd5a32fd6e5a4258ce00a314&oe=589AAD2F

Result:

*https%3a%2f%2fscontent.xx.fbcdn.net%2fv%2ft1.0-1%2fc15.0.50.50%2fp50x50%2f10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg%3foh%3d6c801f82cd5a32fd6e5a4258ce00a314%26oe%3d589AAD2F*

and the actual request for this specific link would be:

http://localhost:9876/?url=https%3a%2f%2fscontent.xx.fbcdn.net%2fv%2ft1.0-1%2fc15.0.50.50%2fp50x50%2f10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg%3foh%3d6c801f82cd5a32fd6e5a4258ce00a314%26oe%3d589AAD2F

**Alternate Solution**

I personally prefer POST over GET in this situation, so here it is:

```
public class ReverseProxyController : NancyModule
{
    class ProxyRequest
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }

    public ReverseProxyController()
    {
        Post["/", true] = async (parameters, ct) =>
        {
            var result = await GetResult(parameters, ct);
            return result;
        };
    }

    private async Task<Response> GetResult(dynamic parameters, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var pReq = this.Bind<ProxyRequest>();
        var url = pReq.Url;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            return null;

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6");
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url, ct);

        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();


        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {
            case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK:
                var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                return Response.FromStream(stream, response.Content.Headers.ContentType != null
                    ? response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString()
                    : "application/octet-stream");

            default:
                return Response.AsText("\nError " + response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This IS the problem. I just checked before I saw this answer and it IS missing that last "&oe=589AAD2F".

Comment: Why is nancy truncating off that last query parameter?

Comment: Nevermind...Nancy truncates it because of the way Nancy tokenizes the url...it's giving me what it thinks is the parameter I want. Is there any way to format the route properly to get what I want?

Comment: @richard, you can encode the url before sending it, nancy will automatically decode it for you, e.g. by using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` I got http://localhost:9876/?url=https%3a%2f%2fscontent.xx.fbcdn.net%2fv%2ft1.0-1%2fc15.0.50.50%2fp50x50%2f10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg%3foh%3d6c801f82cd5a32fd6e5a4258ce00a314%26oe%3d589AAD2F and the original code works fine with it, I'll update the answer to reflect that

Comment: Can you also put the original solution with the substring? I can't control what gets sent to nancy so I can't make sure it's urlencoded...

Answer (score 1):

as console application you code works fine

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetStuff();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async void GetStuff()
    {
        CancellationToken ct = new CancellationToken();
        var client = new HttpClient();
        //this is only a Simple Change to demonstrate the problem, and should not be considered as a proper solution

        string url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=6c801f82cd5a32fd6e5a4258ce00a314&oe=589AAD2F";
        if (url == null) return;

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6");
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url, ct);

        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();


        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {
            case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK:
                var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();


                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

i get a OK 200 return message. Is it other images that you use that might need a login information ?